# Jersey Pojo Annotation

Tags: java, xml, jersey

I want to create an XML Web Service using Jersey 2.

I have 2 classes represented here by A and B :

```
public class A {
    private B b;
}

public class B {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String bString;
}
```

and a service class :

```
@GET()
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public ObjetA test(){

    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    a.setB(B);          
    return a;
}
```

Is there an annotation or another way to get the following XML output :

```
<a bString=""/>
```

right now I have this one :

```
<a>
<b bString=""/>
</a>
```

As you can see, I want to show bString which is a B field as an attribute of `<a>`.

Thx.

Comment: Is it possible to change the layout of your classes A and B? Maybe - if you have to keep them - think about adding a new class "AForTheApi" that exposes an @XmlAttribute bString directly.

Comment: Yeah i don't wanna touch my A and B classes and i'm looking for a way to use them instead of using a new class desinged only for the Web Services...

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution, just had to create this method in A :

```
@XmlAttribute(name="bString")
public String getBStringWebService() {
    if(this.getB()!=null){
        return this.getB().getBString();
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```